Eliminating client secret from app registration
I am facing critical issue for app registration in azure, please consider following scenario.
I have one app registration which contains a client secret. We use this app registration to generate authentication token, and this token is used in bearer token to authenticate the Microsoft service.
The URL we are using to generate the authentication token is :

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token

Request body contains:
grant_type = client_credentials

client_id = <--Application ID of app registration-->

client_secret = <--Client secret added in app registration-->

resource = <--microsoft service end point-->

Problem is I want to eliminate this client secret dependency and authenticate the microsoft service without authentication token.
In microsoft document they have suggested 2 ways to tackle this problem. One is to use Federated Identity Credentials and another way is to use Subject Name + Issuer authentication.
But I am not sure which of these options are applicable in above scenario.
I have tried to create FIC on app registration, but while creating it there are certain field values needs to be added and I am not aware about correct values. e.g Issuer scenarion, subject name, identifier etc.
Second option subject name + issuer, suggest changes in code with the help of microsoft authentication library, which we are not using.
Microsoft documents are too much technical and everything is going over my head.
I will be grateful if I could get some inputs with the steps along with screenshots. Thank you.

@Pratik, Hi Pratik thanks for the reference, I have tried that resolution. First of all, when I set allow_public_flow to true, and used given body parameter in that request, it still gives me error like we have to provide client_secret or client_assertion to get the token. I also dig more into that, we must pass client_credentials as value to grant_type, we can not change it to password according to oauth2 documentation.

Hi @AzureKnight, where you able to fix this issue?

Note that: client_secret parameter cannot be excluded from the client credentials flow as it acts like a password to authenticate the Microsoft Entra ID application.

By default, client_secret is a mandatory parameter in client credentials flow.
Client secret is required for confidential web applications.

Hence if you want to exclude client_secret the only option is to set allow_public_flow to true and make use of ROPC flow.

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token

client_id : xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
grant_type : password
resource : resource
username : ruk@********.onmicrosoft.com
password : ******



Only for public or desktop applications, you can exclude client_secret parameter.
In your scenario, you must pass client_credentials as value to grant_type, we cannot change it to password, you need to pass client_secret parameter and cannot be eliminated from the request

